# How do I return queries out of Rails active record so I can pass them back to a client-side log console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, logging, client

When a client hits my Rails app's API for data, I would like to pass back the query that generated the data with the data. I'm using Rails 2.

Right now I've edited the Rails mysql_adapter to put all queries in a global hash that has the user session as a key and the query as a value.

This is very hacky and probably not thread-safe.

Is there a better way?

Comment: if moving to rails 3 is an option, ActiveSupport::Notifications is awesome for that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fake_arel](https://github.com/gammons/fake_arel) gem to get the `.to_sql` functionality into rails 2.

Comment: .to_sql didn't seem to work on methods like: MyClass.find(:all).to_sql  but I was able to look at what fake_arel did and hack it some more to work with the methods I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it can help but you can whenever you want call `to_sql` on an ActiveRecord object :

```
user = User.where(:id => 1)
user.to_sql # Outputs "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"id\" = 1"
```

Comment: Not in rails 2 - that was new in rails 3